# ZeroMq (NetMq) - Xpub Xsub - with docker (issue) cannot expose same port in yaml

Tags: docker, zeromq

- Pub1 --> XSub - XPub --> XSub1
- Pub2 --> XSub - XPub --> XSub2
- Pub3 --> XSub - XPub --> XSub3

My issue is that XSub suppose to listen on specific ip:port, meaning that all Pub1,2,3 have to publish to the same ip:port (conflict and conflict in the docker compose to expose port output in the yaml).

Each publisher are located in their own docker in the same machine 1
Where the Xpub-Xsub and the subscribers are in the same machine 2 each one on their own container.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved, didn't pray attention that my publisher has been configured as server instead client. (bind vs connect )..